# Lazy cartesian product in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, cartesian-product

I would like to generate a rather large but finite Cartesian product in Haskell, which I need to then iterate on (think partition function of a mean-field model). The natural thing to do uses `sequence`, like this:

```
l = sequence $ replicate n [0,1,2]
```

Unfortunately, for large `n`, this does not fit in memory and I run out of heap as soon as I ask for `length l` for instance. I would need a way to do the same thing lazily. I ended up "rediscovering" base-3 arithmetics, like this,

```
nextConfig []     = []
nextConfig (0:xs) = 1:xs
nextConfig (1:xs) = 2:xs
nextConfig (2:xs) = 0:(nextConfig xs)

ll = take (3^n) $ iterate nextConfig $ replicate n 0
```

(which works) but it feels like reinventing the wheel, and besides it is much too specific. What would be a better lazy way to generate the product?

Comment: Do you care about the order of the elements in the result?

Comment: No, as long as there is no repetition.

Comment: How large do you need `n` to be?

Comment: Something like 20 or 30; I don't really care about computation time for now, but certainly `3^n` is beyond RAM size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The more memory-friendly way is obtained by binding in reverse order compared to sequence,

```
foo 0 _ = [[]]
foo k xs = [h:t | t <- foo (k-1) xs, h <- xs]
```

It is slower due to less sharing, but since memory is your problem, maybe it's good enough for you.

Comment: Cool! I will have to investigate more why it works, but it certainly does. I modified it as `foo (l:ls) = [h:t | t <- foo2 ls, h <- l]` (who knows if I will always need a cube) and it works as well. Thanks!

Comment: Why are list comprehensions more efficient than do-notation for lists (which is used in `sequence`)? I can see from the Haskell2010 report both of them desugar to `concatMap`?

Comment: @brence: See Duncan Coutts's answer to this reddit question: [Why are guards in the list comprehension faster than in the do-notation?](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/oolyt/why_are_guards_in_the_list_comprehension_faster/)

Comment: From there, it appears that list comprehension is desugared into `foldr`. The weird thing is that a naive `foldr` approach to cartesian products (at least the one I tried) breaks laziness like `sequence` does ...

Comment: @danr, a few years ago I changed the definition of `concatMap` and/or the `Monad` instance for `[]`, so it should now compile basically the same as the list comprehension version. As I recall, we now define `concatMap f xs = [f x | x <- xs]` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern for an infinite list is from the top-left corner a1 then a2 down to b1, a3 down to c1

```
a1 a2 a3 a4
b1 b2 b3 b4
c1 c2 c3 c4
d1 d2 d3 d4
```

That is, `a1, a2 b1, a3 b2 c1, a4 b3 c2 d1`
The letters in comma separated groups are
`a ab abc abcd` and the digits
`1 21 321 4321`

The infinite list output should grow diagonally first with a1 then with 2 added diagonally then 3 added diagonally and so on.

Either of the above single letters or digits must progress in reverse.

```
diag xs ys = [(a,b)| (m,n) <- zip (inits xs) (inits ys), (a,b) <- zip m $ reverse n ]
```

With a reverse with every `(m,n)` pair. I prefer to reverse all at once, one operation repeated. The reverse of an infinite list can, I think, only be accomplished with successive reverse lists.

```
rsl = tail.scanl (flip (:)) []

take 5 $ rsl [1..]

[[1],[2,1],[3,2,1],[4,3,2,1],[5,4,3,2,1]]
```

Then handle each list in turn. `zip` limits the non-reversed list in each iteration.

```
plr xs ys = [ (a,b) | ls <- rsl xs, (a,b) <- zip ls ys ]

sort.take 10.plr ['a'..] $ [1..]

[('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('a',4),('b',1),('b',2),('b',3),('c',1),('c',2),('d',1)]
```

`sort`, because taking values diagonally means they are not in order like the first linear list above. `sort` is imported from **Data.List**

As an aside, because this is traversing diagonally triangular numbers come into play. I used `take 10` above, The triangular numbers are:

```
take 11 [sum ls | ls <- rsl [1..]]

[1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55,66]
```

Comment: Hi, some activity on that very old question! but I'm not sure how your reply relates to it, did you perhaps intend it for another question?

Comment: `diag` is a lazy cartesion product. Try it. As I said, I prefer a lazy function to impliment the reverse lists, that is, lazy `rsl`. `plr` is another lasy cartesian product function that uses lazy `rsl`. If you do not use `take` with all of these functions they will run forever.